# Redis Cache - Access HMSET using Redisson

Tags: redis, redis-cache, redisson

I have `HMSET` stored in Redis Cache as below

```
>hmset [User1] [Key1] [value1] [Key2] [value2]
```

Now how do I get the key and value Map using `User1` key in Redisson ? Also how to get value for specific key and user?

I tried

```
RMap<String, String> map = client.getMap( "User1" );
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RMap<String, String> map = client.getMap( "User1" );
```

This only provides you a handler to operate on the Redis hash object, you will need to invoke the get method to retrieve values of those fields you may require. For instance:

```
RMap<String, String> map = client.getMap( "User1" );
Object value1 = map.get("Key1");
Object value2 = map.get("Key2");
```